# custom listview slow processing

Tags: android

I created a custom `ListView` and followed the below procedure provided by google
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

But the `ListView` scrolling is too slow. Any solutions?

Here is my code of getview

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(convertView==null){
        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridlevelinflate, null);
        holder=new ViewHolder();
        holder.levelImg=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.lvlPic);
        holder.levelName=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.lvlName);
        holder.levelLeft=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.lvlLeft);          
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.levelImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.ruzzle);
    holder.levelName.setText("Level " + position++);


    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Large Image Sizes could cause such slowness.

Answer (score 0):

**There's nothing in this code that stands out as a significant inefficiency that would make your ListView slow.  The problem is probably somewhere else.**

That said, here are the things that are less efficient than they could be:

- Since it's constant, you could move the `setImageResource` call into the initial holder setup (when `convertView == null`), but I wouldn't expect that to be terribly slow unless `R.drawable.ruzzle` is extremely complex (and perhaps not even then).
- You're finding `R.id.lvlLeft` and then not using it, so that could be removed, but it's minor as it only happens when views aren't recycled.
- You could use `position+1` instead of `position++`, but that's incredibly minor and won't make any perceptible difference.